# How do I Request Data with 3 Parameters Map<> ? Java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, request

I am trying to send 3 POST parameters in a Volley `String` Request, default is only use 2 parameters. But I have to send 3 parameters on my project. How do I make it like that?

I've tried to add String Parameters in `Map<>`

```
`@Override
protected Map<String, String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("username", username);
  params.put("password", password);
  params.put("type", type);
  return  params;
}`
```

Error Message :

> Wrong number of type arguments: 3; required 2.

Comment: Map is a key-value pair store which means it will have only two parameters, key and the value associated with the key. So, just remove third parameter. Rest of the code is fine. It doesn't mean that if you add third entry in `Map`, you have to add third parameter as well. Create an `HashMap` instance and you can keep on put entries into it. Please take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the type dimension to express storing extra key-value pairs. Those two types refer to the key-value types of ALL the key-value pairs in the map regardless of whether it contains zero, one, two, or more key-value pairs. So your code can be fixed very simply per below.

````
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("username", username);
  params.put("password", password);
  params.put("type", type);
  return  params;
}```
````